# Type of Generic Type as Dictionary Key not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I created a custom exception filter for my web api application. The filter is fairly simple and uses a dictionary to map exception types to http status codes.

```
this.Mappings = new Dictionary<Type, HttpStatusCode>
{
    {typeof (ArgumentException), HttpStatusCode.BadRequest},
}
```

The problem I have is that I have defined a generic exception type:

```
class EntityNotFoundException<TEntity> : RepositoryException { /*... */ }
```

And I want to map this exception type to `HttpStatusCode.NotFound`.

```
this.Mappings = new Dictionary<Type, HttpStatusCode>
{
    {typeof (ArgumentException), HttpStatusCode.BadRequest},
    {typeof (EntityNotFoundException<>), HttpStatusCode.NotFound},
}
```

However, because generics generate multiple classes at compilation, none of the instances of EntityNotFoundException actually matches the key of my mappings.

For example if I do:

```
throw new EntityNotFoundException<User>(userId);
```

The filter does grab the exception, however ­­­­`typeof(EntityNotFoundException<>)­­­­` and `typeof(EntityNotFoundException<User>)` does not generate the same hash.

I see two options:

1. Remove generic and add a Type argument to my exception's ctor;
2. Map `EntityNotFoundException<User>` to `HttpStatusCode.NotFound`, which will create a mapping for each of my entity.

Is there any cleaner solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert a specific generic type to it's general generic type (example: from `List<int>` to `List<>`) by using the following:

```
if (exceptionType.IsGenericType)
{
    exceptionType = exceptionType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
}
```

Then you can do the lookup in your dictionary to find the `EntityNotFoundException<>`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you sir, I must wait 5 minutes to accept.

Comment: No problem! You can also use GetGenericArguments() to find the specific type that threw the exception if need be. :)